# Bloomberg RBblpapi with bds

Tags: r, bloomberg

I am trying to access Bloomberg via R using the Rblpapi package. I am executing the following commands

```
library(Rblpapi)

con <- blpConnect()
opt <- c("START_DT"="19990101", "END_DT"="20160101")
bds("CPI YOY Index","ECO_RELEASE_DT_LIST", options = opt, con = con)
blpDisconnect(con)
```

I get the following error, "Error: Sub-element '(null)' does not exist.". It has something to do with the options. I can get data in excel with these options, so I am not sure what is missing. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me when you omit the start and end date:

```
R> library(Rblpapi)
R> bds("CPI YOY INDEX", "ECO_RELEASE_DT_LIST")     
   Ecostats Release Date
1               20150116
2               20150226
3               20150324
4               20150417
5               20150522
6               20150618
7               20150717
8               20150819
9               20150916
10              20151015
11              20151117
12              20151215
13              20160120
14              20160219
15              20160316
16              20160414
17              20160517
18              20160616
19              20160715
20              20160816
21              20160916
22              20161018
23              20161117
24              20161215
R>
```

Also note that we prefer bug reports etc as issue tickets at GH.

Comment: Definitely works without the options in R but it also works with the options in the excel API. I want to get all dates starting 1999/01/01. That cannot be achieved without additional options. I will file a bug report on github. Thanks for taking a look.